# Sqlite or shared preference is better for data fetching with MPAndroid Library on the basis of daily ,Weekly,Monthly basis?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, sharedpreferences, mpandroidchart

i am making Bar graph with use of MPAndroid Library.
On X-axis of Bar Graph data may be as daily,Weekly,Monthly or yearly basis.

I want to know what is the best way of data fetching for daily,Weekly,Monthly or yearly basis among SQlite ,SharedPreference,or MySQL(API from Back End)?

Please suggest me what will be good option for above condition?

I want to app should not slow , without internet connectivity data should come.

I think if I will use  MySQL(API from Back End) it may be slow and dependent on Internet.

Please give me suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

You can store data in shared preference in JSON format using gson. Sqlite is little bit slow compared to Shared preference

Comment: Am i correct If I will use Back End API(MYSQL or ROR ) to fetch data from Back End and use shared preference with GSON library . App will not slow during fetch data and without Internet data will be available ?.

Comment: yes you are correct. you load data from local first if available then in background get updated data from server and update again chat based on new data

Comment: So first time if data is not available then get it from web and save in json format in shared preference for future use to load offline

Comment: Okay Thank you so much .

Comment: one more question for storing data first can use shared preference
Eg- to store Y axis data with respect to x axis

Comment: First of you have to load data from web server in json format as there is blank data in sharedpreference. Once loading data from server is completed then save it in Shared preference using json and bind it with chat  second time and in parentally again request to web server to fetch updated data and again replace it in shared preference